# Is "Airman ga Taosenai" grammatical?

Tags: particle-が, particle-を, song-lyrics, potential-form

I've been listening to this memetic song for quite a bit, but recently I was thinking perhaps the title could be inaccurate. Shouldn't it be "Airman wo Taoserarenai"?

There are 2 points I have to make here:

One, たおせない means "to not beat/defeat" when the song clearly sings about not being **able** to defeat Airman, which would be expressed by the negative potential form of 倒せる: 倒せられない.

Two, the object is エアーマン, not the player, so エアーマン needs a を instead of a が, right?

Am I on the mark on these two counts?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opADNvgeZYY

More on the song: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Man_ga_Taosenai

Comment: The expressions for potential and passive forms are never fully distinguished; られる still holds the double meaning even today , and in older forms of the language this was probably only more common. The use of が for direct object is most probably generalized here from the passive sense of the same expression.

Comment: Apologies, I mistakenly thought that 倒れる was the dictionary form. Turns out 倒す is the dictionary form, which would mean 倒せる for potential and 倒せない for negative potential.

Passive would be 倒される　and negative passive would be 倒されない. This means that られる confusion is absent in the title above. Many thanks for the reply though!

Comment: But Airman is like the easiest boss, even with the Mega Buster...

Comment: Maybe see [可能表現の対象格標示「ガ」と「ヲ」の交替](https://www.jpf.go.jp/j/project/japanese/archive/globe/18/08.pdf) by 青木ひろみ (2008).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Not defeat' is 倒さない, not 倒せない. 倒せない means 'not be able to defeat'. As for が vs を, the potential form ('be able to', 'can') is traditionally used with が, I think in either of the following manners: 僕にはエアーマンが倒せない, or 僕はエアーマンが倒せない, but it's becoming more and more frequent to use it with を like this: 僕はエアーマンを倒せない.

Comment: Thanks, this has been really helpful! However, after a bit of Googling, I thought perhaps 僕に/が エアーマンが 倒せない should have a は in front instead? To me it makes sense that 僕 should be the topic, rather than a subject (が) or a target (に) - 僕は エアーマンが 倒せない.

The following examples show a は and a が, and were taken from http://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/potential-form.html/

兄は泳げます。
My elder brother can swim.

母は日本料理が作れます。
My mother can cook Japanese dish.

弟は自転車に乗れます。
My younger brother can ride the bicycle.

Comment: @rhyaeris I only used が because は replaces が; a relative clause would have 僕が倒せないエアーマン, but the main clause would be 僕はエアーマンが倒せない. It's a little complicated to elaborate.

Comment: 僕はエアーマンが倒せない is more natural, than 僕が～. You explaining エアーマン, 僕が倒せないエアーマン is correct because 僕 isn't the subject.

Comment: As a dependent noun phrase, 僕で/にエアーマンが倒せない(こと)

Comment: ^「僕**で**エアーマンが倒せない」「僕**で**エアーマンが倒せないこと」 はおかしいです。

Comment: @Derpius I meant 僕が倒せないエアーマンは-type sentences. I just probably have used a full sentence.